# How else can I avoid leaking this Core Foundation object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks, core-foundation

The following leaks:

```
CFStringRef labelName = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(aMultiRef, indexPath.row));
    cell.textLabel.text = (NSString *)labelName;
    CFRelease(labelName);
```

Wondering if there a way to rewrite it so it doesn't leak without breaking out & assigning `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(aMultiRef, indexPath.row)` to a `CFStringRef` that I then need to manually `CFRelease` 2 lines later? Of course, it's not a big deal to do just that...I'm just curious.

**Edit:** Would `CFAutoRelease` work? see my comment below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Copy/Get semantics you are required to release anything that comes out of an API with `Copy` in it. `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex` meets that requirement, so unfortunately you'll need to acquire this reference and release it later on.

Comment: What about `CFAutoRelease`? could `CFStringRef labelName = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(CFAutoRelease(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(aMultiRef, indexPath.row)));` work?

Comment: There is no `CFAutoRelease`; you should store references to anything you create temporarily in a local variable and `CFRelease` it when finish.

Comment: @rpetrich in iOS7 SDK, there is CFAutorelease in CoreFoundation/CFBase.h

Comment: @thandasoru Yup, finally.

Answer (score 0):

You can autorelease using Objective-C (so long as you have a pool in place). Just cast to id first. E.g. [(id)labelName autorelease] will work fine and it’s perfectly legal (because CFStringRef is and toll-free bridged with NSString). You can actually do this with any CoreFoundation based type, although I don’t believe Apple publicly document this so in theory, this could change.